# ReactJS: How to add a new element in array state and to preserve "prevState" for them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My array state is rendering and i can to push new elements without problem, but, when i trying add in specific index, react is changing the state of the previous elements.
Example of the previous state:

```
{this.state.numOfRows.map((v, k) => (
    <Item add={this.add.bind(this)} key={`item-${k}`} index={k} item={v} />
))}
```

This will render a  html element with option = 0;
So, when i call this.add(index) prop i can push 2 or 3 more elements on my array and i change options for 1 and 2.
But, when i call this.add(index) to add a new element in index 2, for example, then the previous options that i selected are updated and the new element  with 0 in option is displayed in the last index.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKwnK.png)

Comment: your issue is you are using the index of the array for the `key`. Instaed use something more specific like a unique id from the database. the second issue is how you are adding the items. Use `splice` on a copy of the array to mutate / insert at an index `arr.splice(idx, 0, item)`

Comment: Thank you @JohnRuddell. It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering lists in React, you should specify a `key` that is based on the unique identity of the item being rendered, rather than the (current) index/position of that item in the source array.

In your case, if each items in the `numOfRows` array had a unique identifier (ie `someUniqueId` as shown below) then this would be a better candidate for use with the `key` prop of each `<Item />` that is rendered:

```
{
  this.state.numOfRows.map((v, k) => 
      (<Item add={this.add.bind(this)} 
             key={`item-${ v.someUniqueId }`} 
             index={k} 
             item={v} />))
}
```

The reason for this is that React determines if an item in a rendered list  needs to be updated based on that items `key`. Rendering anomalies will arise when an item's `key` (based on it's index) remains the same despite the actual data for that item changing.

For more information on this, see React's [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) documentation.

Also, see this [in-depth article on the `key` prop](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) and specifically, [this summary of when an index based key prop is okay](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#a4ca).